# jQuery validate with Ajax submission of a form

Tags: jquery, ajax

The validation for mine works on a regular PHP form, but on this Ajax form, it would only work some of the time. Usually after the submit button has been clicked once, the validation won't run again a second time. I feel like I need to bind the validation with the Ajax, but am unsure how to proceed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var J = jQuery.noConflict();
    J(document).ready(function(){
    // Validate signup form on keyup and submit
    J("#professorform").validate({
        rules: {
            "professor":
            {
                required: true,
                format: true},
            },
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addProf(str)
    {
        if (str=="")
        {
            document.getElementById("prof").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        { // Code for Internet Explorer 7 and later, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        { // Code for Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 5.
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);

        var params = "professor=" + encodeURI(document.getElementById("professor").value);

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("prof").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.send(params);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code when you could just use the ajax() jQuery function.

Comment: why don't you use the ajax functions of jQuery? They are far more comfortable

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem but you can replace all that AJAX setup and callbacks by using the jQuery AJAX command. Check it here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
It will be a lot cleaner and it's a lot easier to write.

Comment: Thank you!!  I've switched to the ajax() jquery function and it definitely is MUCH cleaner!  But I'm still stuck on how to get the validation to bind to it...

Comment: Try to call the validation function in the `beforeSend` callback of the AJAX function.